# UI Testing - Access the Camera

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I get permission alert box when i first trigger the app cam on UI test on real device. To avoid crash and follow my ui test steps, i tried to the following steps. But still not working as i want. Any ideas to avoid crash?

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.buttons[@"Open Camera"] tap];

XCUIElement *alert = app.alerts[@"\u201cSampleAppObjC\u201d Would Like to Access the Camera"].buttons[@"OK"];
if (alert) {
    [alert tap];
}
...
[app.buttons[@"Flash"] tap];
[app.buttons[@"Help"] tap];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way to allow a permission for the first trigger the cam

```
//system camera alert for permission
id systemAlertMonitor = [self addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription:@"Alert Handler" handler:^BOOL(XCUIElement * _Nonnull interruptingElement) {

if (interruptingElement.buttons[@"OK"].exists) {
        [interruptingElement.buttons[@"OK"] tap];
        //Return YES if handled the alert
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}];
```